# Upgraded from .NET 4x project to .NET Core: CS0579 Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute' attribute

Tags: .net, .net-core

After upgrading from .NET 4.x to .NET Core, I start getting CS0579 errors:

> Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute
> Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute' attribute
> Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute' attribute
> Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute' attribute
> Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute' attribute
> Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute

There are 2 solutions, below.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 Keep AssemblyInfo.cs**

Add the following attributes to the .csproj file:

- GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute: Controls the generation of the AssemblyDescription attribute.
- GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute: Controls the generation of the AssemblyTitle attribute.
- GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute: Controls the generation of the AssemblyProduct attribute.
- GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute: Controls the generation of the AssemblyVersion attribute.
- GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute: Controls the generation of the AssemblyFileVersion attribute.
- GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute: Controls the generation of the AssemblyInformationalVersion attribute.
- GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute: Controls the generation of the AssemblyCompany attribute.
- GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute: Controls the generation of the AssemblyConfiguration attribute.
- GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute: Controls the generation of the AssemblyCopyright attribute.

As per:

```
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
```

**Option 2: move meta-data into .csproj**

1. Set the meta-data in the .csproj file
2. Delete the Properties folder and AssemblyInfo.cs file
   Further info: https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/setting-assembly-and-package-metadata/